# How to make the CircularProgressBar or other spinner work in Flutter with BottomNavigation and Named Routes?

Tags: flutter

How To make CircularProgress run by the time data is being loaded from the API? The Function from the main.dart calls the page, which has this logic from the Apple.dart, which gets its data from Future, which is connected to an API

"Trying the isLoading = false method but didn't help"

On Apple.dart

```
bool isLoadingFromApple = false;

class _AppleState extends State<Apple> {
  final getPost = NetworkFile().getCategories(2219);

  List posts = [];

  void getPostsList() async {
    var res = await getPost;
    setState(() {
     posts = res;
     isLoadingFromApple = true;
    });
  }
}
```

on main.dart

the pages are imported already

```
List<Widget> _widgetOption = <Widget>[
  HomePage(),
  Google(),
  Microsoft(),
  isLoadingFromApple ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Apple(),
  Others(),
];
```

Expected result: Progress Spinner continues until the background data is downloaded.

Actual: Stuck on the Progress Spinner

Answer (score 0):

You are showing Progress Spinner after posts are getting loaded.

Either Do as :

```
List<Widget> _widgetOption = <Widget>[
  HomePage(),
  Google(),
  Microsoft(),
  !isLoadingFromApple ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Apple(),
  Others(),
];
```

Or

```
List<Widget> _widgetOption = <Widget>[
  HomePage(),
  Google(),
  Microsoft(),
  isLoadingFromApple ? Apple() : CircularProgressIndicator() ,
  Others(),
];
```

Comment: It gets stuck on ProgressIndicator

Comment: you need to add more to your question as its not clear when and when functions are called & updated.